# How to derive Clone for structures with boxed closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I have the following structure:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
   foo: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>
}
```

And I want to derive `Clone` for `MyStruct`. However, the compiler turns out error:

```
the trait bound `dyn std::ops::Fn(usize) -> usize: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
```

And for now (rustc 1.46.0), the `dyn` does not support addition of non-auto traits like `Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize + Clone>`.

From the [rust-reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits):

> A closure is `Clone` or `Copy` if it does not capture any values by unique immutable or mutable reference, and if all values it captures by copy or move are `Clone` or `Copy`, respectively.

So I think this derivation makes sense in theory, but I don't know if I can do it for now.

I don't mind manually implementing `Clone` for `MyStruct`, but I don't know how to do it, either.

I don't want to do something like

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct<F: Fn(usize) -> usize> {
    foo: F
}
```

because this struct is used as an associated type for an implementation of another struct for a trait, and both that struct and the trait has no generics, and I don't want to messed up with `PhantomData`.

Comment: The usual trick is to use something like `trait CloneFn<T>: Clone {}

impl<T, U> CloneFn<U> for T where T: Fn(U) -> U, T: Clone {}` but then you'd run into the problem that `Clone` isn't object-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @mcarton comment above, but using the [`dyn-clone`](https://crates.io/crates/dyn-clone) crate to overcome `Clone` not being object safe, the code is quite straightforward.

```
use dyn_clone::DynClone;

trait FnClone: DynClone {
    fn call(&self, x: usize) -> usize;
}

impl<F> FnClone for F
    where F: Fn(usize) -> usize + Clone
        
{
    fn call(&self, x: usize) -> usize {
        self(x)
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
   foo: Box<dyn FnClone>
}

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            foo: dyn_clone::clone_box(&*self.foo),
        }
    }

}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct{
        foo: Box::new(|x| x + 1)
    };
    let b = a.clone();
    println!("{} {}", a.foo.call(1), b.foo.call(2));
}
```

This crate also provides a macro [`clone_trait_object!`](https://docs.rs/dyn-clone/1.0.2/dyn_clone/macro.clone_trait_object.html) to make the `Clone` derivable for the `Box<dyn FnClone>`, but you don't seem to want that.